# Find the least amount of intervals which cover highest range

Tags: c#

I would like to ask for a hint how to approach in solving this task:

I have intervals ordered by min. value eg: ([1,5],[2,9],[6,7],[8,16],[11,15], [18,20]).
I should pick minimal amount of intervals, which cover the largest range.

So I should store these: ([1,5],[2,9],[8,16],[18,20]). Interval [6,7] is not stored, because it is covered by interval [2,9]. Interval [11,15] is not stored, because it is covered by [8,16].

How should I approach in solving this? Thank you:)

Comment: highest range? or target range? cause in case of highest range, answer might be the combination of min number of range which covers the whole range.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind storing `[2,9]` rather than `[6,7]` in your example? Storing `[6,7]` instead would lead to less overlap in your stored intervals: `([1,5],[6,7],[8,16],[18,20])`. (Edit: Least/Most possible overlap may not be a requirement, but I think it's relevant to know if it should be considered.)

Answer (score 1):

Linq approach

```
int[][] input = new[] { new[] { 1, 5 }, new[] { 2, 9 }, new[] { 6, 7 }, new[] { 8, 16 }, new[] { 11, 15 }, new[] { 18, 20 } };
int[][] result = input.Where((i1, x1) => !input.Where((i2, x2) => x1 != x2 && i2[0] <= i1[0] && i2[1] >= i1[1]).Any()).ToArray();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1xosT

**Update:** Thanks to @yuriy-faktorovich I've a added a `<=` and `>=` comparison instead `<` and `>`. Also removed the comparison with itselve.

Comment: You still have an issue with `new[]{new[]{1, 5}, new[]{2, 6}, new[]{4, 7}}`. But let's say you fix it for that case. The question is still whether a single pass is enough to find the final solution.

Comment: `new[]{new[]{1, 5}, new[]{2, 6}, new[]{4, 7}}` looks good, none of them gets removed becase one is covered by another one

Comment: But 2, 6 should be removed as the range is covered by 1,5; 4, 7.  Unless I misunderstood the instructions.

Comment: I think those are all separate ranges

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is keep track of the current highest range and only store numbers that are higher.

So the first highest number would be 5 so you store it, then add 9 and make it the highest number, then you reach 7 which is less than 9, so it's not stored, then you add 16 and make it the highest, 15 is less than 16, so skip it, and then finally add 20.

idk what language you're using, but the code would look something like.

```
foreach(var item in dataset)
{
    if(item[1] > highest)
    {
        savedItems.Add(item);
        highest = item[1];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there could be local maximums, so I wrote the recursive function to look at different options

```
static List<(int lower,int higher)> Minimize(List<(int lower, int higher)> list, int i = 0)
{
    //past last item
    if (i >= list.Count) return list;
    
    if (( i > 0 && list[i - 1].higher >= list[i].higher) || 
        (i + 1 < list.Count && list[i + 1].lower == list[i].lower) ||
        (i > 0 && i + 1 < list.Count && list[i + 1].lower - list[i - 1].higher <= 1))
    {
        var newList = list.ToList();
        newList.RemoveAt(i);
        var minimizedNewList = Minimize(newList);
        var minimizedCurrentList = Minimize(list, i + 1);
        return minimizedNewList.Count < minimizedCurrentList.Count ? minimizedNewList : minimizedCurrentList;
    }
    else return Minimize(list, i + 1);
}
```

You can test with the following

```
var testData = new[] {(1, 5), (2, 9), (6,7), (8, 16), (11, 15), (18, 20)};

var result  = Minimize(testData.ToList());

foreach (var valueTuple in result)
{
    WriteLine(valueTuple);
}

WriteLine("----------------------------");

testData = new[] { (1, 5), (5, 6), (6, 7) };

result = Minimize(testData.ToList());

foreach (var valueTuple in result)
{
    WriteLine(valueTuple);
}

WriteLine("----------------------------");

testData = new[] { (1, 10), (5, 6) };

result = Minimize(testData.ToList());

foreach (var valueTuple in result)
{
    WriteLine(valueTuple);
}

WriteLine("----------------------------");

testData = new[] { (1, 10), (1, 20) };

result = Minimize(testData.ToList());

foreach (var valueTuple in result)
{
    WriteLine(valueTuple);
}
```

Here's a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/EC5BrW

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.